# jQuery/JavaScript: Event handlers only assigned during the last iteration of a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, event-handling, for-loop

I'm having a problem whereby a loop which is instantiating two objects, which in turn create elements and attach event handlers, only actually attach the event handlers for the last iteration of the loop. While I'm aware of issues with scope inside anonymous functions in a loop, I can't see how that is applicable here, and I'm left scratching my head...

So, first, a setContent method of a view object iterates over an array of content, and creates two instances of the CrowdControl.ui.Button object: (irrelevant code removed for clarity)

```
setContent: function(content){
    if(content.length > 0){
        for(var i in content){
            var c = content[i];

            var container = $('<div></div>');

            //content array code removed for clarity

            var reject = new CrowdControl.ui.Button({label:'Reject'});
            var approve = new CrowdControl.ui.Button({label:'Approve'});

            container.append(reject.draw());
            container.append(approve.draw());

            this.contentlist.addItem(container);


        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Button object (again some code removed for clarity)

```
CrowdControl.ui.Button = function(){
    this.uniqueId = Math.random(); //added for debugging
    var els = this.elements = {}
    els.container = $('<div class="cc-button"></div>');
    els.label = $('<div></div>').text('Debug'); 
    els.container.append(els.label);
}
CrowdControl.ui.Button.prototype.draw = function(){
        console.log('Drawing element '+this.uniqueId);
        var els = this.elements;
        els.container.remove();

        console.log('Binding click to button');
        console.log(els.container); 

        //attach the click handler - this will only attach during the last iteration
        els.container.click( function(){ console.log('wtf'); });

        return els.container;
}
```

The above code logs that all the elements are made, and they're all unique, but only the last two instances of the Button object receive the event handlers and log 'wtf' when clicked.

Any help would be hugely appreciated - if you need any more code or explanation just ask...

Comment: Hm - it seems this code actually runs just fine in this extremely stripped down form. Which makes this example a bit pointless... I'll try to find an example which is still broken!

Comment: that means there is some error in another part of your code, do you see any console errors or warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help Neal.  It actually turned out the problem was elsewhere in my framework, where a view was incorrectly redrawing after each iteration, and calling .remove() each time, which was of course removing the event handlers from child elements.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed you code: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/E8XcQ/6/

Click should be done like this:

```
//attach the click handler 
$(els.container).click(function() {
    console.log('wtf');
});
```

You accidentally attached the `click` to the DOM element and not the jQuery element

Comment: Thank you, but nope that's not it - els.container is already a jQuery object

Comment: @Andru, did you see my fiddle? the log is logging a DOM element, not a jQuery element. now when you click on anything it logs `wtf`